# Show CLT for Poisson random variables, using no generating function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Question is as following:

> $X\sim Po(\lambda)$
>
> $$\frac{X-\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \,{\buildrel d \over \rightarrow}\,
> N(0,1)$$
>
> as $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$.
>
> **Obs.** One is asked not to show the convergence with generating functions.

I begin by setting $Y=\frac{X-\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$ and thus:

$P(Y\leq y)=P(\frac{X-\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \leq y)$.

After some arrangements:

$P(X \leq y\sqrt{\lambda}+\lambda)$.

The plan after this is to use the cdf of the $Po(\lambda)$ and send $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$. The problem is that the cdf is not given and is expected to be calculated which stops me in my tracks. I tried using $1-P(X>y\sqrt{\lambda}+\lambda)$ but the sum is something that I can not handle.

I also tried the simpler way to derive the cdf by simply doing:

$P(X\leq x) = \sum^x_{k=0}e^{\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$.

But it still stops me...I tried mixing around with the sum such that I could be able to use some known sums but I can't seem to handle it..

Any form of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The admonestation by the OP's TA to "read the book" that was mentioned in a comment (and that the OP instantly dismissed as being due to some kind of psychological disorder their TA would be suffering from) seems rather sound and might be based on the following basic remark.

For every integer $\lambda$, $X_\lambda$ is distributed as the sum of $\lambda$ i.i.d. random variables $\xi_k$ Poisson with parameter $1$. Since $E(\xi_k)=\mathrm{var}(\xi_k)=1$, for integer values of $\lambda$, the desired result directly follows from the standard CLT.

To recover the result for noninteger values of $\lambda$ as well, note that one can realize $(X_\lambda)$ in such a way that $X_\lambda\leqslant X_\nu$ almost surely for every $\lambda\leqslant \nu$. Then, bound the random variable $Y_\lambda=(X_\lambda-\lambda)/\sqrt{\lambda}$ almost surely, using $Y_n$ and $Y_{n+1}$ for $n=\lfloor\lambda\rfloor$, and apply the previous case.

Comment: I 'll have to read up on it when i'm home!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** after the editing of the question, the following does not match the request -- indeed, it is based (solely) on characteristic functions...

---

Using characteristic functions, for $Y=\frac{X-\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$ and any $t\in\mathbb{R}$:
$$
\mathbb{E} e^{it Y} = e^{-it\sqrt{\lambda}}\mathbb{E} e^{i\frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}}X} = e^{-it\sqrt{\lambda}} e^{\lambda(e^{it/\sqrt{\lambda}}-1)}
$$
using the expression of the characteristic function of a Poisson random variable (applied to $u=\frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$). Now, for any fixed $t$, we have 
$$\begin{align}
-ita+a^2(e^{i\frac{t}{a}}-1) &= -ita+ + a^2\left(i\frac{t}{a}+\frac{i^2t^2}{2a^2} + o\!\left(\frac{1}{a^2}\right)\right) \\
&= -ita+ ita+\frac{i^2t^2}{2} + o(1) = -\frac{t^2}{2} + o(1) \\
&\xrightarrow[a\to\infty]{} -\frac{t^2}{2}
\end{align}$$
so that $e^{-it\sqrt{\lambda}+\lambda(e^{it/\sqrt{\lambda}}-1)} \xrightarrow[\lambda\to\infty]{} e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$ (applying the above with $a=\sqrt{\lambda}$).

But recalling that $\phi\colon t \mapsto e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}$ is the characteristic function of a normal random variable $\mathcal{G}(0,1)$, this means that the characteristic function $\phi_Y$ converges pointwise to $\phi$, or [equivalently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_continuity_theorem#Theorem) that $$Y\xrightarrow[\lambda\to\infty]{d} \mathcal{G}(0,1)$$
as claimed. $\square$

Comment: This answer is indeed correct and I've also solved it through the C.F, it was the question before this one. The problem is that in this question they explicitly ask you to use the C.F. But the fault is mine and I will edit this in to the question!

Comment: They explicitly ask you *not* to use the characteristic function, or they explicitly ask to use the cdf? (that is, not another method, which would be neither CF nor cdf)?

Comment: They explicitly say not to use any generating functions, that is the cf,pgf and the mgf.

Comment: Mmmh.. unless there is a way to use the definition in terms of convergence of $\mathbb{E} f(Y)$ for any $f$ continuous and bounded, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Me and my friends asked our professor and he told us "read the book" and then dismissed us.. He isn't particularly fond of students..

Comment: Well, if he ever gives the answer, please let me know what he expected... I'm quite eager to understand.

Comment: I'll try to hunt him down.

Comment: At a disadvantage not knowing what's in "the book," I wonder if the idea is to emulate the method of proof of the Demoivre-Laplace CLT, which depends heavily on Stirling's formula.