# How to show Poisson = Normal Distribution (in the right limit) without CLT

Tags: calculus, poisson-distribution, central-limit-theorem

If I take the Poisson PDF, 
$$\frac{e^{-\mu} \mu^x}{x!}$$
in the limit that $n$ is around the $\mu$ (i.e., not at the tail of the distribution) and $\mu$ is large this tends to the normal distribution,
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \mu}}e^{-(x-\mu)^2/2\mu}
$$
This is really a statement about functional form so I suspect I should be able to show this without repeating the proof of the central limit theorem. Is there a way to show this using elementary Calculus (without resorting to the Central Limit Theorem)?

Comment: IIRC, there is a "neat" way using Levy's theorem and characteristic functions (show the convergence pointwise of the sequence of characteristic functions).

Comment: There is a difference between a probability (Poisson) and density (Normal), but if you are asking about whether $\dfrac{e^{-\mu} \mu^{\mu}}{\mu!}$ is close to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \mu}}e^{-(\mu-\mu)^2/2\mu}$ then consider Stirling's approximation to the factorial.  An extension might cover cases where $x$ is close to but different from large $\mu$

Comment: Relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1076750/75808